# Vue.js размножение инпутов с v-model/v-for

Tags: vue.js

Изучая вью столкнулся с проблемой, сам решить не могу. 
 Есть код:

https://github.com/irzhakbasil/testApp/blob/master/src/Modal.vue

есть объект :

```
export default {
    callControl: '',
    read: '',
    soundAutoCall: '',
    truck: '',
    origin: '',
    destination: '',
    pickup: '',
    dho: '',
    dhd: '',
    fp: '',
    length: '',
    weight: '',
    trip: '',
    alarm: '',
    actions: ''
}
```

Вопрос - как c помощью v-for и ключей объекта сделать код человеческим?

```
v-model' directly cannot update the iteration variable 'x' itself
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный вариант, где someObj.js файл с вашим объектом.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div v-for="(value, key) in someObj" :key="key">{{value}}</div>
      <input v-for="(value, key) in someObj" :key="key" v-model="someObj[key]"/>     
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SomeObj from './someObj.js'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      someObj: SomeObj,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```